# What is the earliest source available to the worship of Prana?

Tags: scripture, history, practice, worship

What is the earliest reference available for the fundamental belief in worshiping Prana?
Where is it documented the belief that Prana created the world?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AtharvaVeda Samhita contains [**Prana Sukta**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av11004.htm) in 11.4 which glorifies Prana:

> Homage to Prāna, him who hath dominion o'er the universe, Who hath become **the Sovran Lord of all, on whom the whole depends!**
>   
>   Prāna is Fever, he is Death. **Prāna is worshipped by the Gods.** Prāna sets in the loftiest sphere the man who speaks the words of truth.
>   
>   Prāna is Deshtri, and Virāj **Prāna is reverenced by all. He is the Sun, he is the Moon.** Prāna is called Prajāpati.